# Which conditional tag is correct to have a different style on a page

Tags: wordpress, tags, hook

I need to add an ads in a Wordpress page but I'm not able to localize it.

I have tried with the " is_archive " conditional tag but it shows me the ads in the page and not in the subcategory ( page ).
What is the correct conditional tag to use?The structure should be PAGE - CATEGORY - SUBCATEGORY. In the PAGE I put a shortcode ( custom menu wizard plugin ) which display a menù. This menù it's a list of subcategory.

If you want you can check the page ( where i put my name instead of the ads to make a test ) which is this one http://www.alesitiprova.it/acciaio-nodi/ ( I wrote CIAO ALESSANDRA DE ROBERTIS ).

But i would like to show this text by clicking on the link menu ( Altri, Pilastri e fondazioni, Pilastri e Travi ) 
If you click for example in "Altri" you open this page http://www.alesitiprova.it/category/particolari-costruttivi-dwg/acciao-nodi/altri-acciaio-nodi/

In this page i would like to see "CIAO ALESSANDRA DE ROBERTIS ".

Can Someone help me?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.. Each different "type" has it's own conditional logic. E.g., a single page would be `is_single`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the pages you are trying to detect are category archive pages, you should probably use `is_category('slug-of-category')` instead of `is_archive()`.

So for example, if you want to detect the category "Altri", you can use `is_category('altri')`